# Firebase Messaging Package for Unity gives problems when building with Gradle

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, unity-game-engine

At first I could build and install the app on my Android device but as I launched it crashed, the Logcat was saying that a Firebase library was not included in the package and advising to use the Play Services Jar Resolver. So I used it.

Now I have this error when trying to build my app. (excuse me, I had some issues understanding how to insert a code snippet :) )

```
    CommandInvokationFailure: Gradle build failed. 
    /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -classpath "/Applications/Unity/PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer/Tools/gradle/lib/gradle-launcher-2.14.jar" org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain "assembleRelease"

    stderr[
    /Users/andreamarchetti/Desktop/Squarcuit/Temp/gradleOut/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml:4: Error: Avoid hardcoding the debug mode; leaving it out allows debug and release builds to automatically assign one [HardcodedDebugMode]
      <application android:icon="@drawable/app_icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:debuggable="false" android:isGame="true" android:banner="@drawable/app_banner">
```

Explanation for issues of type "HardcodedDebugMode":
   It's best to leave out the android:debuggable attribute from the manifest.
   If you do, then the tools will automatically insert android:debuggable=true
   when building an APK to debug on an emulator or device. And when you
   perform a release build, such as Exporting APK, it will automatically set
   it to false.

If on the other hand you specify a specific value in the manifest file,
   then the tools will always use it. This can lead to accidentally publishing
   your app with debug information.

```
1 errors, 0 warnings
Dex: Error converting bytecode to dex:
Cause: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat$AccessibilityServiceInfoVersionImpl;
    UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
    com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat$AccessibilityServiceInfoVersionImpl;
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:591)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:546)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:528)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:164)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:188)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:504)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:334)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:277)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:245)
        at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':transformClassesWithDexForRelease'.
com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
]
stdout[
Incremental java compilation is an incubating feature.
:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:checkReleaseManifest
:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:Firebase:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:Firebase:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:Firebase:compileReleaseNdk UP-TO-DATE
:Firebase:compileLint
:Firebase:copyReleaseLint UP-TO-DATE
:Firebase:mergeReleaseProguardFiles
:Firebase:packageReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:Firebase:checkReleaseManifest
:Firebase:prepareReleaseDependencies
:Firebase:compileReleaseRenderscript
:Firebase:generateReleaseResValues
:Firebase:generateReleaseResources
:Firebase:packageReleaseResources
:Firebase:compileReleaseAidl
:Firebase:generateReleaseBuildConfig
:Firebase:mergeReleaseShaders
:Firebase:compileReleaseShaders
:Firebase:generateReleaseAssets
:Firebase:mergeReleaseAssets
:Firebase:processReleaseManifest
:Firebase:processReleaseResources
:Firebase:generateReleaseSources
:Firebase:incrementalReleaseJavaCompilationSafeguard
:Firebase:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac
:Firebase:processReleaseJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:Firebase:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForRelease
:Firebase:transformClassesAndResourcesWithSyncLibJarsForRelease
:Firebase:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders
:Firebase:transformNative_libsWithMergeJniLibsForRelease
:Firebase:transformNative_libsWithSyncJniLibsForRelease
:Firebase:bundleRelease
:prepareAnimatedVectorDrawable2340Library
:prepareAppcompatV72340Library
:prepareCardviewV72340Library
:prepareCustomtabs2340Library
:prepareFacebookAndroidSdk4170Library
:prepareFacebookAndroidWrapper794Library
:prepareFirebaseAppUnity401Library
:prepareFirebaseCommon1100Library
:prepareFirebaseIid1100Library
:prepareFirebaseMessaging1100Library
:prepareFirebaseMessagingUnity401Library
:prepareGradleOutFirebaseUnspecifiedLibrary
:preparePlayServicesBase1100Library
:preparePlayServicesBasement1100Library
:preparePlayServicesTasks1100Library
:prepareSupportCompat2520Library
:prepareSupportCoreUi2520Library
:prepareSupportCoreUtils2520Library
:prepareSupportFragment2520Library
:prepareSupportMediaCompat2520Library
:prepareSupportV42340Library
:prepareSupportV42520Library
:prepareSupportVectorDrawable2340Library
:prepareReleaseDependencies
:compileReleaseAidl
:compileReleaseRenderscript
:generateReleaseBuildConfig
:mergeReleaseShaders
:compileReleaseShaders
:generateReleaseAssets
:mergeReleaseAssets
:generateReleaseResValues
:generateReleaseResources
:mergeReleaseResources
:processReleaseManifest
:processReleaseResources
:generateReleaseSources
:incrementalReleaseJavaCompilationSafeguard
:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac
:compileReleaseNdk UP-TO-DATE
:compileReleaseSources
:lintVitalRelease
:prePackageMarkerForRelease
:transformClassesWithDexForRelease
To run dex in process, the Gradle daemon needs a larger heap.
It currently has approximately 910 MB.
For faster builds, increase the maximum heap size for the Gradle daemon to more than 2048 MB.
To do this set org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048M in the project gradle.properties.
For more information see https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html
:transformClassesWithDexForRelease FAILED

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 45.841 secs
]
exit code: 1
UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo psi, UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg)
UnityEditor.Android.GradleWrapper.RunJava (System.String args, System.String workingdir, UnityEditor.Android.Progress progress)
UnityEditor.Android.GradleWrapper.Run (System.String workingdir, System.String task, UnityEditor.Android.Progress progress)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.BuildGradleProject.Execute (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context)
UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessRunner.RunAllTasks (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context)
UnityEditor.HostView:OnGUI()
```

---

I do not have  - `android:debuggable="false"` -anywhere in any AndroidManifest.xml in my project.

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code

Comment: Please do not bump your question by posting a non-answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem was that I had multiple .aar files of the same package but different versions. So Facebook SDK was conflicting with some Google Firebase stuff. I deleted the Facebook SDK .aar (which were older versions).